# Given a method, how to obtain the class that defines this method?

Tags: python, class, methods, python-datamodel

If this is a classmethod, this task is simple:

```
class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    def some_fun(cls):
        pass

fun = MyClass.some_fun
my_class = fun.__self__
print (my_class is MyClass)  # True
```

However, it only works because `some_fun` is a `classmethod`. Let's make it a regular method and the above code stops working:

```
class MyClass:
    def some_fun(self):
        pass

fun = MyClass.some_fun
my_class = fun.__self__  # AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__self__'
print (my_class is MyClass)
```

The above code raises `AttributeError`.

Is there any way to retrieve `MyClass` given `MyClass.some_fun` if `some_fun` is a regular method, and not a `classmethod`?

Comment: `fun = MyClass.some_fun` in this case, I can only think of approaches that rely on hacky introspection (e.g. using `MyClass.some_fun.__qualname__`). A *method* is just a *normal function* that is an attribute to a class that gets called via an instance, whereby the descriptor protocol automatically binds the instance as the first object, and returns this new bound-method object (on each invocation! that's why `some_instance.some_method is not some_instance.some_method`). Attributes have no direct knowledge of the objects they belong to.

Comment: So, there are hacky ways at least, but a better question is, why do you need this at all?

Comment: `f = MyClass.some_fun: print(f.__qualname__) --> 'MyClass.some_fun'` - so you could split the qualified name on the *dot* to get the name of the class.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I guess my quest to minimize repetitive code brought me to some dark areas of un-pythonicness and obscurity... Still I have no better idea how to remove the repeating code

Comment: @gaazkam fundamentally, unless you are writing some static code analyzer, your code shoulnd't *care* where something is *defined* (note, a method doesn't even have to be defined in the *same module*, let alone in the class definition). This screams [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should tell us what you are *actually* trying to accomplish.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But I fear a question like: "How do I best remove repetitive code given this case" will get downvoted and closed as subjective. I'd love to ask this question, given that I seem to be between a rock and a hard place: copypastes or ugly hacks: and that my coworker already snidely remarked that at this rate I'm gonna soon write a compiler; only I'm afraid that SO rules prevent me from asking it!

Comment: Well, you should at least give more context here in this question. That won't hurt.